# Is there an equivalent python function of matlabs rankfeatures function?

Tags: python, matlab

Does anyone know of a function in one of the python libraries, scipy, scikit learn, numpy.... that does the equivalent of what `rankfeatures` does in matlab, from the matlab documentation:

rankfeatures:

[IDX, Z] = rankfeatures(X, Group) ranks the features in X using an independent evaluation criterion for binary classification. X is a matrix where every column is an observed vector and the number of rows corresponds to the original number of features. Group contains the class labels.

IDX is the list of indices to the rows in X with the most significant features. Z is the absolute value of the criterion used (see below).

Group can be a numeric vector or a cell array of strings; numel(Group) is the same as the number of columns in X, and numel(unique(Group)) is equal to 2

http://www.mathworks.com/help/bioinfo/ref/rankfeatures.html?

Comment: You're more likely to get useful answers if you briefly explain what `rankfeatures` does in matlab.